# Extrusion along a curve for a certain face

Tags: bezier-curves, faces, extrude

Is there any way to extrude a certain face along a curve?
I couldn't find anything on this.
I have used the curve modifier and i am familiar with it.
It works on the whole mesh rather than some particular faces which I select.

So any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ranger, looks like you didn't finish your sentence. Could you go back and Edit your post please?

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.  Choose wisely.  Show a `Curve modifier`, for example, coordinated with your work.

Comment: I didn't know what happened. As I completed my full question.

Answer (score 0):

**Various Options** .. You may only need one

1. Use the vertex group entry of the `Curve Modifier` to Limit the area  of shape influence.
2. Use `proportional edit`
3. Use an `armature` to control the shape of an
   extrusion.
4. Consider `Spline IK Constraint`

---

See tutorials on any one of these suggestions. Blender Stack Exchange BSE, can be searched on these topics. You can also search the famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob. This was to list various options and is not a tutorial on any of the ideas.

Comment: OK thanks brother atomicbezierslinger. I will research the topics you have pointed. Thanks a lot.